# populate select data options then saved from other table with hasMany relation

Tags: cakephp-3.x

I have problem when save result select data options from other tables.
below this orm hasMany

> > table usertraces hasMany signs

```
table userTraces
+-----+------------+------------+
+ ID  +  Username  +   sign     +
+-----+------------+------------+
+  1  +   John     +   swollen  +
+  2  +   John     +   bloody   +
+-----+------------+------------+

table signs
+-----+------------+
+ ID  +   sign     +
+-----+------------+
+  1  +   swollen  +
+  2  +   bloody   +
+-----+------------+
```

below sampe code to populate

```
table method signsTable
$this->belongsTo('Usertraces', [
     'foreignKey' => 'usertrace_id'
  ]);

table method usertracesTable
$this->hasMany('Signs', [
     'foreignKey' => 'usertrace_id'
]);

in usertraces controller
<?php
public function testkueri()
{
      $usertrace = $this->Usertraces->newEntity();
      $sign =
$this->set('signs', $this->Usertraces->Signs->find('list'));
      $usertrace->Gejala = $this->set('signs', $this->Usertraces->Signs->find('list'));
      if ($this->request->is('post')) {
          $usertrace = $this->Usertraces->patchEntity($usertrace, $this->request->getData());
          if ($this->Usertraces->save($usertrace)) {
               $this->Flash->success(__('Deteksi gejala berhasil disimpan'));
           return $this->redirect(['action' => 'testkueri']);
         }
       $this->Flash->error(__('Deteksi gejala gagal disimpan, coba lagi'));
      }
      $this->set(compact('sign'));
      $this->set(compact('usertrace'));
      $this->set('_serialize', ['usertrace']);
}
?>

in testkueri.ctp

<?php
  echo $this->Form->create($usertrace);
  echo $this->Form->control('Username', array('type' => 'text'));
  echo $this->Form->control('sign', array('type' => 'select', 'options' => $signs));
  echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

the query populate select options success work, but can't saved in usertraces table, the result in column signs is >null

```
below the null result in table usertraces
+----+----------+----------+
+ ID + Username +   Sign   +
+----+----------+----------+
+ 1  +  John    +    null  +
+ 2  +  John    +    null  +
+----+----------+----------+
```

I hope someone help me to fix trouble, thanx for your help,...

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a `hasMany` relation, your form variable needs to be named like `signs.0.id` instead of `sign`. If you had a second such field, like if you wanted to allow people to add two signs, the second one would be `signs.1.id`. If your control was a multi-select, then it should be called `signs._ids`.